# A proper way to compile angular template into html, convert result into string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Abstract

Hi, I'm using angular to render documents, I have the view-model that contains the data which should go into document, and I have angular template that represents the document. The template is valid angular-html markup that is later rendered using angular's **$compile**, here is directive I use to render documents for presentation purposes:

```
angular.module('app').directive('render', function ($compile, server) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            var scope;

            server.resolve().then(function (repo) {
                var _template, _constants, _variables, _substitutes;

                var render = function () {
                    if (_template) {
                        $scope.repo = repo;

                        var references = repo.references;

                        if (_constants) {
                            for (var constantName in _constants) {
                                $scope[constantName] = references[_constants[constantName]];
                            }
                        }

                        if (_variables) {
                            for (var variableName in _variables) {
                                var substitute = _substitutes[variableName];
                                var variableValue = _variables[variableName];

                                var reference = repo.references[substitute];

                                if (reference) {
                                    if (reference.table === variableValue) {
                                        $scope[variableName] = reference;
                                    } else {
                                        throw new Error('Invalid reference type');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (scope) scope.$destroy();

                        scope = $scope.$new();

                        var element = angular.element('<div class="print"></div>');
                        element.html(_template);

                        $element.empty();
                        $element.append(element);

                        $compile(element)(scope);
                    }

                };

                $scope.$watch($attributes.template, function (template) {
                    _template = template;
                    render();
                });

                $scope.$watch($attributes.constants, function (constants) {
                    _constants = constants;
                    render();
                });

                $scope.$watch($attributes.variables, function (variables) {
                    _variables = variables;
                    render();
                });

                $scope.$watchCollection($attributes.substitutes, function (substitutes) {
                    _substitutes = substitutes;
                    render();
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

## Question

I need to make a hard-copy of the document, in other words I need to substitute the view-model values into document template, convert result into string and put it into variable. I can't use directive for that, angular's $compile is really heavy function to call, it creates watches under the hood, I don't need whole shebang, I just need to substitute values. What would be the best way to do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please add what your service `server` is returning? Does it return your template with a http request?

Comment: Adding server would raise more questions than provide answers, basically yes it's sort of data channel on top of $http, I'm aware of security concerns in that regard if I have guessed what you mean...

Comment: No, I just wanted to better understand your code. At the moment, I'm creating a demo fiddle to create what you'r looking for. But I don't excatly understand what you want to save in a variable. Do you want to save the compiled template with added context in a variable? Or only the compiled template with-out context?

Comment: I'd like to put the resulted html into database so that when the view-model changes the document itself will remain unchanged, in any case I've managed to resolve the problem, I've got around with `$interpolate` service it handled the job nicely, I've responded with an answer but stack-guys deleted it because it was short, not sure how helpful zero answers would be to stackoverflow users rather than zero and a half...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your tip for [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) I could finalize my demo for your question.

It's with-out a service for storing the interpolated template into database to keep the demo focused on the issue.

So as I've understood, the difference between `$compile` and `$interpolate` is the following:

- `$compile`: Creates DOM elements with angular binding to scope. That's what you would normally use to render your DOM to have two-way binding etc. working. In most cases you don't call it manually because if you add `template` or `templateUrl` to the direcive definition object it will run `$compile` automatically.
- `$interpolate`: It is pretty similar to compile with the only difference that it will return the DOM elements wiht-out angular bindings.

You can see the difference if you have a look at the rendered html markup. Compiled templates have `ng-binding` class in the markup and the other is just static html with-out that class.

So as you mentioned `$interpolate` is the way to go to get the compiled string that you can easily store in the database with a `$http` service.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/9ve4bxfz/).

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('render', Render);

var templateStore = [];
function Render($compile, $interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controllerAs: 'render',
        controller: function () {
            this.hello = 'hello from controller';
            //console.log($templateCache.get('testTemplate'));
            
        },
        compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
            return function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
                //controllers.hello = 'hello from controller';
                //console.log(controllers);
                var template = angular.element(
                    document.getElementById('template.html')).html(),
                    compiled = $compile(template)(scope),
                    obj = {
                        render: {
                            hello: "hello from 'fake' controller" 
                        },
                        hello: 'hello from other object.'
                    };
                
                scope.hello = "Hello from scope";
                element.replaceWith(compiled);
                
                var result = $interpolate(template)(scope);
                templateStore.push(result);
                
                var result = $interpolate(template)(obj);
                templateStore.push(result);
                
                //console.log(result);
                //console.log(templateStore[0]);
                
                $('#test').append( // append just to test the saved template
                    templateStore[0]);
                $('#test2').append( // append just to test the saved template
                    templateStore[1]);
             
            };
        }
    }
}

Render.$inject = ['$compile', '$interpolate'];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
        <div>
            <p>controllerAs: {{render.hello}}</p>
            scope: {{hello}}
        </div>
    </script>
    <h2>Compiled template with binding</h2>
    <render></render>
    
    <h2>The following is a string copy from above template with-out binding</h2>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <h2>You can also $interpolate a object with the following result (also no binding)</h2>
    <div id="test2"></div>
</div>
```